# Rails split string with multiple parts

Tags: ruby, csv, split

I have a string that's been imported from a csv such as:

> 14th Aug 2009:1, 15th Aug 2009:1, 16th Sep 2015:1|Style1, 17th Sep
>   2015:1|Style 1

I wish to add this data to my database in a specific way. First I split it on `,` to get each date group (in this case 4 dates).

Secondly i'd like a way to split each of those date groups into multiple segments. The first with the date, second with the number after the colon and then a varied amount more for each of the items separated by the `|` character.

Is there an decent efficient way to accomplish this in Ruby?

Looking for outcome to be a hash like so:

```
{ '14th Aug 2009' => 1, '15th Aug 2009' => 1, '16th Aug 2009' => 1, '16th Sep 2015' => { 1 => 'Style 1' }, '17th Sep 2015' => { 1 => 'Style 1' }
```

Basically if the string was like so:

> 15th Aug 2009:1, 16th Sep 2015:3|Style1|Style 1, 17th Sep
>   2015:1|Style 1

I would get

```
{ '15th Aug 2009' => 1, '16th Sep 2015' => { '', 'Style 1', 'Style 1' }, '17th Sep 2015' => { 1 => 'Style 1' }
```

Basically, the text separated by `|`'s should be assigned to the number after the colon. If the number is 3 and there are two sets of text after it then one is an empty string and the other two will say the text (eg: "Style 1".

Sorry for sounding very confusing.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the output should be? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your example output format is not valid: `{ '', 'Style 1', 'Style 1' }`. Do you mean to use an array instead? Like: `[ '', 'Style 1', 'Style 1' ]`?

Comment: `string.split(", ").each_with_object({}) { |line, hsh| k, *tokens = line.split(/:|\|/); hsh[k] = tokens }` should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you meant for the '|' separted items to build an Array, as infused asked about. How about this?

```
s ="15th Aug 2009:1, 16th Sep 2015:3|Style1|Style 1, 17th Sep 2015:1|Style 1"
result = {}
s.split(',').each do |v|
  date,rest = v.split(':')
  items = rest.split('|')
  if items[0] == "1"
    result[date] = 1 
  else
    result[date] = ['', items[1..-1]]
  end
end
```

Comment: This looks good so far. I'll give it a go tonight. I'll need to tweak it to create appropriate records in my DB but I can see the general idea. Thanks. Could you explain further about what this line is doing? `result[date] = ['', items[1..-1]]`

Comment: Much appreciate this. I modified it to create the required records in my database that I needed and then extended it further with more required functionality.  Thanks for giving me a great starting point and to get me going on resolving this!